# C++ vector erase function explaination

Tags: c++, vector

I was running the following code:

```
v1.assign(10,50);
v1.insert(v1.end(),22);
cout << "v1 > " << endl;
print(v1);
// prints 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 22
v1.erase(v1.begin()+2)v1.assign(10,50);
v1.insert(v1.end(),22);
cout << "v1 > " << endl;
print<int>(v1);

v1.erase(v1.begin()+2);

for (int i=0;i<11;i++)
    cout << v1[i] << " ";
cout << endl << endl;;

for (int i=0;i<11;i++)
    cout << v1[i] << " ";
cout << endl << endl;
```

According to me, the expected output must be:

```
50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 22
```

( 9 times 50, one time 22 )

but it actually is:

```
50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 22 22
```

( 9 times 50 )

Comment: You are accessing the `vector` out of bounds (it only has 10 elements) -> *undefined behavior*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your second `v1.assign(10,50);` basically resets the vector giving 10 times 50
then you append a 22 giving a vector of length 11
then you erase 1 element giving a vector of length 10

thefore your loop:

```
for (int i=0;i<11;i++)
    cout << v1[i] << " ";
```

accesses the vecor out of bound giving you whatever value sits in memory next to the vector.

loop a vector like this to prevent such mistakes:

```
for (const auto& element : v1)
{
    cout << element  << " ";
}
```